Passkey registration is not displayed in Settings > Accounts > Passkeys
Starting in Windows 11, version 22H2 with KB5030310, we can use the Settings app to view and manage passkeys saved for apps or websites. Go to Settings > Accounts > Passkeys
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/passkeys/?tabs=windows
I implemented authorization using Windows Hello in my application, following the example in the documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport), but passkey registration in my personal account is not displayed. Does anyone know what the problem is?
After registering with
KeyCredentialRetrievalResult keyCreationResult = await KeyCredentialManager.RequestCreateAsync(userName, KeyCredentialCreationOption.ReplaceExisting);
everything works correctly, but it is not displayed in the personal account. The windows version corresponds to the version that is needed to manage passkeys

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
